# Why browser is trying to download my php script file?

Tags: php, firefox, browser

Just a quick one - I wrote a php script recently that dynamically creates XML file using API DOM. So I'm using this at the beginning:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
```

And at the end it looks like this:

```
$server = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$path_to_xml = "$server/project/file.xml"; 
file_put_contents($path_to_xml, $dom->saveXML());
```

It does everything I wanted but why browser is trying to download this php script instead of just run it? Please can someone help me with this. I'm pretty sure it's something easy.
//-----------------------------------edited
Thanks for all replies. Yes I'm sending custom headers because it's google maps kml file that I'm creating dynamically.

header('Content-type: application/vnd.google-earth.kml');

```
// Creates the root KML element and appends it to the root document.
$node = $dom->createElementNS('http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0', 'kml');
$parNode = $dom->appendChild($node);
```

Could that be possible cause of this?

Comment: What web server are you using? Is it Apache?

Comment: Are you sending any custom headers? Have other PHP scripts worked fine before? Can you post the rest of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file extension is `.php` and your web server correctly configured it will run it.

You specify an `application/xxx` content type so most browsers will force a download and use the name of your script as file name.

If you want to force a file name different from your php file name use :

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=your_requested_file.kml');
```

Comment: Thanks Virtual for the answer but this is not what I wanted. The thing is I don't want to download anything here. I just want to create the .kml file in the background and put it in the folder on the server and that's it - no downloading

Comment: So, why are you specifying a Content-Type to the USER BROWSER via header() if you don't want that ??????? You tell the browser that you will send him a file, he download it, that's as simple as that even if you send him nothing he will download a 0k file. If you don't want him to download the file just don't send this header.

Answer (score 5):

Because your web server is not correctly configured to process PHP scripts.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Could you please provide more details on that? What do I have to change in my server config?

Comment: @Pavel Please answer the comment questions first. Is PHP installed at all? What server are you using?

Comment: It is apache and php is installed because I'm running other script without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced that it happens due to some error in the .htaccess, it may seem absurd because i did not mentioned anything to see in the .htaccess. You should take a closer look in to it.

Answer (score 1):

If the browser is trying to download the PHP source, then this means that Apache was either not configured to run the PHP interpreter and/or, if you are using a Linux, Unix, or Mac OS X operating system, Apache did not have permission to execute the PHP script.

You need to follow the instructions at [Manually Configure PHP5 and Apache2](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Manually-configure-PHP5-and-Apache2-62975.shtml) to make sure that your `httpd.conf` is correct.

If, in addition, you are running Apache on Linux, Unix, or Mac OS X, then you need to open a terminal, `cd` into the directory that contains your PHP script, and:

```
chmod a+x SCRIPT.php
```

where `SCRIPT.php` is the name of your PHP script.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that this command sends a header:

```
header('Content-type: application/vnd.google-earth.kml');
```

If you're writing a file on the server and not intending to send any response to the client, why are you sending a header to the client?

If your PHP file is just supposed to write a file on the server and do nothing else, don't send a header or indeed anything else to the client.

If that doesn't help, try rephrasing your question. You have received a wide variety of responses so far to all manner of different problems.

Answer (score 0):

You might not be sending correct headers:

```
<?php header ("content-type: text/xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the browser is not trying to download the PHP script, but IS trying to download the KML file.  Comment out the `header()` line and see if it works.  When saving a file locally, you should not need to include `header()`.

Comment: Too slow again.  Mark got it first.